# AngularJS - information at mouse pointer after hover

Tags: angularjs, hover

In my AngularJS 1.3 application I have this calendar, the unique cells are clickable:

[image]

What I will do is that if mouse is over e.g. 12. April and of user 3 (Marktl) than

```
12. April 2017
Marktl
```

should be shown next to the mouse pointer.
Is there a way of doing this (maybe with support of AngularJS)?

Here my html code of the calendar written by my own:

```
<table class="absenceOverviewTable tableShadow">
<thead>
    <tr class="first-header">
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th class="center first month-header" data-ng-repeat="value in vm.currentMonthNames track by $index">{{value}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="scheduleAbsenceUserContainer in filtered = (institution.scheduleAbsenceUserContainers">
        <td>
            <div class="userNameColumn" title="{{scheduleAbsenceUserContainer.institutionUserRole.value | translate}}"></div>
        </td>
        <td data-ng-repeat="scheduleAbsenceMonthContainer in scheduleAbsenceUserContainer.scheduleAbsenceMonthContainers">
            <table class="days-table">
                <tr>
                    <td data-ng-repeat="scheduleAbsenceDayContainer in scheduleAbsenceMonthContainer.scheduleAbsenceDayContainers track by $index">
                        <div class="data-table-pos border-color width-100">

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you need a dropdown box on cell mouseover? If so, show code of the calendar, is it a library or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your original question exactly what behaviour you want.

If you want something to appear as a tooltip on hover of the cell, you could just  use the regular html `title` attribute. Downside with that is it won't appear immediately, you have to hover for like 2 seconds.

If you want a tooltip to appear immediately, you could try something like Angular Material's tooltip: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tooltip